# PHP / preg_match / regex format

Tags: regex, preg-match

Can't seem to figure this one out. Guess I am more of a newb than I had thought. What I really need is for the code to validate 2-7 7-9 12-10.

Where the numbers before and after the dashes can be one or two digits and the sequence of "number dash number" MUST occur two or three times WITH spaces in between. Right now though I can't even get something as basic as the code below to work!

```
$regex ="/[0-9]{2,3}/";
if(!preg_match($regex, $tiebreaktest)){
$form->setError($field, "* Incorrect Tiebreak Test Format");}
```

This prevents the user from only submitting one number but also lets them add four. I was under the impression that {2,3} limited the range from 2-3 numbers.

Maybe I'm doing something else wrong?

Thanks for anyones help. I am new to stack overflow and hope that I can return the favor in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
^(?:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})(?:[ ](?:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})){1,2}$
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/iT4hJ7)

Testing it-

```
$regex = "/^(?:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})(?:[ ](?:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})){1,2}$/";
$values = Array(
            "2-7 7-9 12-10",
            "2-7 7-9",
            "2-7",
            "2"
        );
foreach($values as $v){
    print_r($v."<br />");
    if(preg_match($regex, $v)){
        echo "Match";
    }else{
        echo "No Match";
    }
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
/* OUTPUT */
2-7 7-9 12-10
Match

2-7 7-9
Match

2-7
No Match

2
No Match
```

EDIT -
Your original regex - `/[0-9]{2,3}/` matches minimum 2 digits and maximum 3 digits. If 4 digits were provided, it would match the first 3 and return that as the result.
If you only want to match minimum 2 and upto(and including) 3 characters in a line, you need to use the start(`^`) and end(`$`) anchors like this - `/^[0-9]{2,3}$/` 
This would mean that the line must have min 2 and max 3 numbers, nothing more and nothing less.
Test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/hF8mN7).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for you fast response. I guess I should of been more specific. The numbers can actually be anything. Any set of numbers can be one or two digits. i.e. 12-5 11-9 89-4 doesn't matter for any of the sets. What does matter is that the "number dash number" sequence occurs two or 3 times with a space. Thanks again for your fast response.

Comment: @CoachJeff Er... but doesn't the current regex satisfy it? The above code is just tests the regex and the $values array are test cases out which some dont match.

Comment: Yes it does! Yes it does! Thank you. There was no way I was getting that on my own.

Comment: By the way. Could you tell me why my original, simpler code didn't work to just test having two or three numbers submitted? thnx

Comment: @CoachJeff Check the edit. If you want a really comprehensive and good tutorial for regexes, visit this [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)